# VBA Looping through 2 different sized ranges

Tags: vba, excel

Not even sure if it's possible or the logic behind it (only started VBA last week) but I need help in looping through two different ranges that are different sizes but with similar IDs.

On one sheet I have about 1500 rows, and about 700 unique IDs, and on the second sheet I have 650 rows, all unique. Problem I have is at the moment, it'll loop through the 650 rows, but I'm about 100 short due to the extra unique IDs in the first row.

Code I have so far is below, probably a few others things wrong with it, or I'm doing things that could cause different problems, but still learning so any help would be appreciated.

Oh,I can get it working by changing comparison3 back to Sheet2!R2C1:R700C1, but I'm hoping I can get it to work with as little set values as possible.

Atm, I'm getting an error on

```
 Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & " = " & comparison3 & ")*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),2)"
```

as comparison 3 range has less unique values to go through than comparison.

```
Function compare(FieldName As String, FieldName1 As String, FieldName2 As String) As Boolean

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lRow1, lRow2 As Long
Dim aCell As Range, rng1 As Range, aCell1 As Range, rng2 As Range, aCell2 As Range, aCell3 As Range
encrypt = True
Dim x As Integer
x = 2
Dim comparison As String
Dim comparison1 As Integer
Dim comparison2 As String
Dim comparison3 As String
Dim comparison4 As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim aCellComparison, aCellComparison1, aCellComparison2 As Range
Dim a As Integer
a = 2

 Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook

 With wkb

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set ws1 = wkb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    '~~> Find the cell which has the name
 Set aCell = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find(FieldName, LookAt:=xlWhole)
 Set aCell1 = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find(FieldName1, LookAt:=xlWhole)
 Set aCell2 = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find("HOS_PROC_FIXED_COST", LookAt:=xlWhole)
 Set aCell3 = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find(FieldName2, LookAt:=xlWhole)
 Set aCellComparison = ws1.Range("A1:Z1").Find("Code", LookAt:=xlWhole)
 Set aCellComparison1 = ws1.Range("A1:Z1").Find("LOS", LookAt:=xlWhole)

  If aCell Is Nothing Then
        compare = False
  End If

  If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
  lRow = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) &    ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lRow1 = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell1.Column).Address, "$")(1) & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lRow2 = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell2.Column).Address, "$")(1) & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



 Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(x, aCell.Column), ws.Cells(lRow, aCell.Column))
 Set rng2 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(x, aCellComparison.Column), ws1.Cells(lRow,  aCellComparison.Column))
 If lRow And lRow1 And lRow2 > 1 Then
            '~~> Set your Range


    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    y = aCell2.Column
 For Each c In rng1

        comparison = ws.Cells(x, aCell.Column).Value
        comparison1 = ws.Cells(x, aCell1.Column).Value
        comparison2 = ws.Cells(x, aCell3.Column).Value
        comparison3 = ws1.Cells(a, aCellComparison.Column).Value
        comparison4 = ws1.Cells(a, aCellComparison.Column).Value

        Range("J" & x).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False


        If ((x > 2) And (comparison <> ws.Cells(x - 1, aCell.Column).Value)) Then
            a = a + 1
        End If

    If comparison2 = "1" Then

     Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & " = " & comparison3 & ")*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),2)"

    ElseIf comparison2 = "2" Then
        Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & "=    Sheet2!R2C1:R700C1)*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),3)"
    ElseIf comparison2 = "3" Then
        Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & "=  Sheet2!R2C1:R700C1)*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),4)"
    ElseIf comparison2 = "6" Then
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & "=       Sheet2!R2C1:R700C1)*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),5)"
    End If

    x = x + 1
Next



End If
End If
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest you use a Scripting.Dictionary object?  In your VBA IDE, go to menu Tools->References and from the available reference check the library marked Microsoft Scripting Runtime.  Then you can write code such as the following which compares two sets of code

```
Sub T()


    Dim dicFirst As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicFirst = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'loop adding numbers from first set
    Dim v
    For Each v In Range("FirstIDs").Cells
        dicFirst.Add v, Empty
    Next v


    Dim dicSecond As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicSecond = New Scripting.Dictionary

    'loop adding numbers from second set
    For Each v In Range("SecondIDs").Cells
        dicSecond.Add v, Empty
    Next v

    'to find all ids in first but not second...
    For Each v In dicFirst.Keys
        If Not dicSecond.Exists(v) Then
            Debug.Print v & " in 1 but not 2"
        End If
    Next v

    'to find all ids in second but not first ...
    For Each v In dicSecond.Keys
        If Not dicFirst.Exists(v) Then
            Debug.Print v & " in 2 but not 1"
        End If
    Next v

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now myself. Just incase anyohe else needs it in future. Code is below.

```
Function compare(FieldName As String, FieldName1 As String, FieldName2 As String) As Boolean

Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lRow1, lRow2 As Long
Dim aCell As Range, rng1 As Range, aCell1 As Range, rng2 As Range, aCell2 As Range, aCell3 As Range
encrypt = True
Dim aCellUnique As Range
Dim x As Integer
x = 1
Dim comparison As String
Dim comparison1 As Integer
Dim comparison2 As String
Dim comparison3 As String
Dim comparison4 As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim aCellComparison, aCellComparison1, aCellComparison2 As Range
Dim a As Integer
a = 2

Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook

With wkb

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set ws1 = wkb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    '~~> Find the cell which has the name
Set aCell = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find(FieldName, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set aCell1 = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find(FieldName1, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set aCell2 = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find("HOS_PROC_FIXED_COST", LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set aCell3 = ws.Range("A1:Z1").Find(FieldName2, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set aCellComparison = ws1.Range("A1:Z1").Find("Code", LookAt:=xlWhole)
Set aCellComparison1 = ws1.Range("A1:Z1").Find("LOS", LookAt:=xlWhole)


If aCell Is Nothing Then
        compare = False
 End If

 If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
 lRow = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell.Column).Address, "$")(1) & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lRow1 = ws.Range(Split(ws.Cells(, aCell1.Column).Address, "$")(1) & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lRow2 = ws1.Range(Split(ws1.Cells(, aCellComparison.Column).Address, "$")(1) & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



 Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(x, aCell.Column), ws.Cells(lRow, aCell.Column))
 Set rng2 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(x, aCellComparison.Column), ws1.Cells(lRow2,  aCellComparison.Column))
 If lRow And lRow1 And lRow2 > 1 Then
            '~~> Set your Range


    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    y = aCell2.Column

 For Each c In rng1

        x = x + 1
        comparison = ws.Cells(x, aCell.Column).Value
        comparison1 = ws.Cells(x, aCell1.Column).Value
        comparison2 = ws.Cells(x, aCell3.Column).Value
        comparison3 = ws1.Cells(a, aCellComparison.Column).Value
        comparison4 = ws1.Cells(a, aCellComparison1.Column).Value

        If ((x > 2) And (comparison <> comparison3)) Then

                a = a + 1
                comparison3 = ws1.Cells(a, aCellComparison.Column).Value
                comparison4 = ws1.Cells(a, aCellComparison1.Column).Value

        End If



  If comparison <> comparison3 Then
    Do Until comparison = comparison3
        x = x + 1
        comparison = ws.Cells(x, aCell.Column).Value
        comparison1 = ws.Cells(x, aCell1.Column).Value
        comparison2 = ws.Cells(x, aCell3.Column).Value
    Loop

        End If





        Range("J" & x).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False


    If comparison2 = "1" Then

     Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & " = " & comparison3 & ")*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),2)"

    ElseIf comparison2 = "2" Then
        Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & "= Sheet2!R2C1:R700C1)*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),3)"
    ElseIf comparison2 = "3" Then
        Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & "= Sheet2!R2C1:R700C1)*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),4)"
    ElseIf comparison2 = "6" Then
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
            "=INDEX(Sheet2!R2C1:R700C7,MATCH(1,(" & comparison & "= Sheet2!R2C1:R700C1)*(" & comparison1 & "= Sheet2!R2C7:R700C7),0),5)"
    End If

Next



 End If
 End If 
 End With
 End Function
```